# Show/Hide hidden files without restarting finder?

Tags: mac, finder, macos

I came to understand that the following is the way to toggle the visibility of hidden files:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES
# replace YES with NO to hide hidden files
killall -HUP Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```

**Is there a way to show/hide hidden files without killing the Finder?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On macOS Sierra, version 10.12.4 and above, you can press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> <sub>(period)</sub>, to toggle hidden files inside of Finder.

Late edit: This currently works on Mojave too, as of b5, 18 Aug 2018.

Comment: @fd0, It states, "... to toggle hidden files inside of Finder.", and the key word here is "toggle", which typically implies pressing the same shortcut key combo both hides/unhides hidden files in this use case. +1

Comment: Do you know the equivalent on non-US versions ?

Comment: Don't forget that you can use that same keyboard combination in Open/Save dialog boxes to temporarily show hidden files.

Comment: Still works in Apr 2019!

Comment: @ogerard see https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/409496/57290

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** This no longer appears to work since El Capitan. `killall Finder` seems to be the only way now.

This is my current El Capitan method, which should also work for Mountain Lion & older

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState & "; killall Finder"
```

---

For Mavericks & Yosemite…

You don't need to restart the Finder, only refresh the windows.

This Applescript will toggle the state & refresh...

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState


tell application "Finder"
    set theWindows to every Finder window
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in theWindows
        set this_item to item i of theWindows
        set theView to current view of this_item
        if theView is list view then
            set current view of this_item to icon view
        else
            set current view of this_item to list view

        end if
        set current view of this_item to theView
    end repeat
end tell
```

*Credit to [ganbustein](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/103711/ganbustein) for the improved hide/show routine*

Comment: You don't need the `tell application "System Events"` block around the two `do shell script ...` commands. In fact, I'm surprised System Events allows you to tell it to invoke `do shell script`.

Comment: I'm no expert in it - I've always just used system events if i don't appear to have 'anybody in particular' to tell;-)

Comment: It "always worked" because System Events is returning an error code that means "do it yourself", and the script is silently doing just that to handle the error. The problem is that you would be invoking `do shell script` with some other app's privileges without giving it a chance to vet the script. Apple made that change to close a security hole where you could ask a program running as root to do your script for you.

Comment: @ganbustein I've pasted your version into a couple of other places on SE I've used this in an answer. Thanks for the input. Most appreciated.

Comment: This is great, except that it doesn't change the Desktop itself. Is there was a way to do that too, other than restarting the Finder?

Comment: You could always just open ~/Desktop as a folder. I rarely keep anything on mine & the odd bits of .DS_Store etc don't hold much interest for me, so I've never actually thought about it before.

Comment: Do you know how to get this working in OSX 10.11? I keep getting `The action 'run shell script' encountered an error`

Comment: I've not tried it on 10.11 yet - only spent a day on it before rolling back; too much still to fix for my liking.