# Showing hidden files on the desktop. Is there a way to remove .DS_Store on desktop only?

Tags: automator, macos

I hope I do not have to disable the  hidden file visibility in order to disable .DS_Store from appearing on the desktop.

.DS_Store constantly gets in the way in the desktop but not in any other folder.

I have a specific strategy in mind to remove .DS_Store on the desktop only. I would like to run an automator app that scans the desktop as a watcher. As it watches changes on the desktop, I would like it to detect the addition of a .DS_Store file and once it detects it, it would automatically move it to the trash (or a folder aside from the desktop.)

I am running El Capitan (osX 10.11) on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: If you keep throwing away the .DS_Store file, your files/folders won't remember their arrangement. Personally, I use this method which, though manual, actually accidentally doesn't show desktop invisibles, only those in folders - http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177138/85275

Comment: @Tetsujin, you may have found the answer for me there. I will test this weekend.

Comment: @Tetsujin the link you provided works! But I modified the script to quit finder and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [XtraFinder](https://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/), and it has the option to show all hidden items except for the desktop.