# How to show hidden files on mac using mouse (without Terminal or Keyboard shortcuts)

Tags: macos

I want to see the hidden files in all the directories of mac. Also, I want to change this setting so that even after restarting mac I should be able to see these hidden files/folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the 'old-style' Terminal command, the view ought to stick through reboots.

The simple Terminal command is

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE; killall Finder
```

However, as you want to do this by mouse only, you will need to wrap this into an Applescript, saved as an application.

From my own answer at [How to set ⌘ + H to enable show hidden files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177132/how-to-set-h-to-enable-show-hidden-files) if you use the following script, saved as an application, you can invert the hidden flag by simply double-clicking the app.

```
set newHiddenVisiblesState to "YES"
try
    set oldHiddenVisiblesState to do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles"
    if oldHiddenVisiblesState is in {"1", "YES"} then
        set newHiddenVisiblesState to "NO"
    end if
end try
do shell script "defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles " & newHiddenVisiblesState & "; killall Finder"
```