# Automator, Show/Hide hidden file

Tags: automator, macos

I'm still running El Capitan so I don't have that shortcut for show/hide hidden files. A while ago I've created automator service, which using the keyboard shortcut could show/hide hidden file depending on previous state. I've clean installed the os and decided to recreate what I did before, and I am stuck on getting `if [ Commandresult = State ]; then` part to work.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles = "FALSE" ] 
then
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
else 
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE
killall Finder
fi
```

I've seen [Show/Hide hidden files without restarting finder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168540/show-hide-hidden-files-without-restarting-finder), but I know it could be shorter like this since I had it working with something like this before.

Comment: The reason it fails in a clean install is because the `AppleShowAllFiles` _key_ does not exist in the `com.apple.finder` _plist_ file. You can quickly solve the issue by executing the following _compound command_ in Terminal: `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles FALSE; killall Finder` Otherwise, you'll need to write the `if` _statement_ to handle the fact that the `defaults` _command_ is not returning the expected _boolean_.

Comment: @user3439894 I have ran those commands in sh, and do you have any idea why `defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles = "FALSE"` always return FALSE regardless of what AppleShowAllFiles boolean is. It is the same problem when I remove double quotation from FALSE in command.

Comment: Change `if [ defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles = "FALSE" ]` **to:** `if [ "$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)" = "FALSE" ]`

Comment: @user3439894 Thank you so much, it now works perfectly

Comment: The is also a way to Show/Hide files from menu bar. The automator service can be downloaded from [Toggle Hidden Files](https://sourceforge.net/projects/toggle-hidden-files/). When installed, you can select `Finder->Services->Toggle Hidden Files` from the menu bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` *statement* test,`[ ... ]`, is not properly formed, change:

```
if [ defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles = "FALSE" ]
```

To:

```
if [ "$(defaults read com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles)" = "FALSE" ]
```