# Finder: Show/Hide hidden files with non-US keyboard

Tags: finder, shortcut

I discovered the well-known shortcut  `⌘ CMD` + `⇧ SHIFT` + `.` to quickly show and hide hidden files in finder. Unfortunately, this shortcut doesn't work on non-US keyboards.

How can I show/hide files using a shortcut with AZERTY keyboard?

Note:

- I know I can update `com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles` and kill the finder, but I am looking for a shortcut based solution.
- I currently work with macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to get it working on a non-QWERTY keyboard.

Comment: It's didn't worked for me. So I've used terminal for the solution `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE;killall Finder`

Comment: @Fatih that will definitely work, but there is definitely keyboard shortcuts available to reveal hidden files, but it may be specific to your type of keyboard layout, or if you somehow changed the keyboard shortcut for some other application it may overwrite the hidden files keyboard shortcut.