# Can't codesign due to " .DS_Store files cannot be a symlink"

Tags: macos

I'm trying to get an app notarized, which was written in python and converted to an .app using pyinstaller. It functions perfectly well.

When I attempted to codesign, I entered the following at the command line:

```
codesign -s "PaulF (TeamID)" -v --deep --timestamp --entitlements 
/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/entitlements.plist -o runtime 
/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_Application.app
```

entitlements.plist is apparently required since binaries were created using pyinstaller. It's contents can be viewed at https://haim.dev/posts/2020-08-08-python-macos-app/.

The message I receive states ".DS_Store files cannot be a symlink", which prevents Apple from notarizing the app.

I'm a new developer and have no idea how to interpret and resolve this message. Running Mac 11.3.1 if that helps.

Comment: '.DS_Store' is an index file created and used by the Finder. If it's inside the application, I don't think you want it or need it. I would find it, delete it, and sign again.  Also, maybe try finding out how it got there...

Comment: Thanks. I can't find it anywhere though.

Comment: @fishbacp How are you looking - to remove .DS_Store files DO NOT use the Finder as the Finder creates them

Comment: From the Terminal:  "find MyApp.app -name .DS_Store" will show the paths of any .DS_Store files inside that app directory.  == Oops... I see this is already the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Run this command and then try the code sign a second time

```
find /Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/My_Application.app -name .DS_Store -delete
```

Note - doing this next part will create new .DS_Store files and require a second delete pass described above. Like all files starting with a period, this one is hidden by default in Finder.  [This shortcut toggles the preference to show hidden files in Finder](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292766/5472). Command - Shift - period

Comment: That actually did it! Received an error message from Apple after the .zip was uploaded, but I'll look at the log file and see if I can get that straightened out. Thank you so much!